# Conversion between types in old entity framework 6

Tags: entity-framework

i have  char(6) column in db that represent time (hhmmss)
i want to represent this column in entity model as TimeSpan

in Ef core version its very easy with ValueConvertor /HasCoversion function of modelbuilder object
how to do it on EF 6 in .net 4.72 version?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

In "old" EF6 the best you can do is add an extra [NotMapped] property to expose the converted data.  EF Core has [Value Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?msclkid=15346df7cfee11ecb96f65e951c6351a&tabs=data-annotations) for this.

Comment: thanks.its not help me because i want to add filter on time before invoke.i think the better way its to add another column to db and create trigger on insert/update